# PHP-based database models that sync with database?

Tags: php, database, synchronization, production-environment

Django models are really cool because you define all your models/tables right in the code, and then sync it with the database. That way when you go to update your production server, you just run the migration/sync script and you can't forget to update any tables.

The project I'm working on now though isn't Django or Python-based, it's written in PHP, and all the queries are written in straight SQL (no ORM). We've got many databases that need to be updated every time we make a change. Right now we're basically copying and pasting our SQL scripts and running them where-ever they need to be ran, or if it's a big change, we might use a script. The problem though, is that sometimes we forget to include some SQL.

If, however, we had a code-based solution, then it would automatically get checked in with our pushes, and we couldn't forget to run it. So... I'm looking for a solution that will let us define all our models in PHP, but let us continue to write straight SQL without the use of an ORM (project is 10 years old, would be too much work to implement an ORM right now). Would be nice if it could convert our existing DB into PHP models too.

Are there an existing solutions for this?

Answer (score 2):

I haven't used a PHP-based system with the fantastic model support offered by Django, but this project looks promising: [Django-like PHP querying interface](http://andrewfreiday.com/2011/06/17/further-work-on-a-django-like-php-orm-framework-phrames/)

Comment: I think I need something a little more stable and tested...this sounds like it's written by one guy and it's unfinished.

Comment: Hi Mark, I am the developer of the project linked above. You are certainly correct that is quite unstable and only supported by myself. However, it does very much sound like what you are looking for. If you have a small, non-mission critical web application that you are developing it could still be a very feasible option. I'm hoping my work spreads a bit and others are able to contribute where possible. If not, no offense taken and best of luck!
- Andrew

Comment: Hi Andrew, maybe for a smaller/personal project I could give it a try, but not for this one unfortunately. Thanks for the reply :)

Answer (score 2):

you can use Doctrine2 I guess. There is a support for native SQL http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/reference/native-sql.html

Comment: That Native SQL stuff won't work for us. I want the models without having to modify any existing SQL. With what you're suggesting, I'd have to back and modify every single database query and wrap it with this `createNativeQuery` function. I'll have to look at the rest of it though, maybe it can still do what I want.

Answer (score 2):

This might cost you but this is what we use for old projects.

**SQLYog**

> http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mysql/article.php/1584401/Synchronizing-Your-MySQL-Databases-Using-a-Free-MySQL-Admin-Tool---SQLyog.htm

**DBDeploy** - Opensource

> http://dbdeploy.com/

**PHING & DBDeploy** - how-to

> http://www.davedevelopment.co.uk/2008/04/14/how-to-simple-database-migrations-with-phing-and-dbdeploy/

Comment: Didn't know these tools existed. They sound exactly like what I'm looking for. Perhaps even less work than converting everything to models too... I'll have to give these a try. Thanks!