# Data-aware PHP components?

Tags: php

Many desktop applications (e.g, those built with Delphi) use "Database aware components", such as a grid, which display the contents of a database - usually the result of a query - and auto-update their display when the database contents change.

Does such a thing exist for PHP (maybe displaying the result of a query in an HTML table, and updating)?

If not, how would we go about creating it?

(Note: [This seemingly similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6429033/php-based-database-models-that-sync-with-database) didn't help me)

Comment: Look into Symfony forms: http://symfony.com/doc/2.3/book/forms.html

Comment: how advanced it should be? do You think about something easy or database scripting is also possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not technically possible to update a HTML page once rendered with pure PHP because of the static nature of the HTTP protocol so any solution would have to include JavaScript and AJAX calls.

**Emulating using AJAX to re-render the table every 5 minutes**

It wouldn't be hard to emulate though, just make a PHP page which gets the results of a database and puts them in a table, then use jQuery's `.load()` function to get that table and render it in a `DIV` of your choice on an interval of 5 seconds or whatever.

Something like:

```
function updateTable(){
    $('#tableDiv').load(url);
}
var url = 'renderTable.php';
setInterval(updateTable,5000);
```

You can put this in any PHP (or HTML) page with a `DIV` with id `tableDiv` and it will render the output of `renderTable.php` in that div every 5 seconds without refreshing.

**Actually monitoring the database**

This is possible, you'd have to set up a PHP file on a cron for every 5 seconds (or an AJAX call every 5 seconds) to run something like `SELECT MD5(CONCAT(rows,'_',modified)) AS checksum FROM information_schema.innodb_table_stats WHERE table_schema='db' AND table_name='some_table';` (assuming innoDB), you'd then compare this to the previous checksum.

If the checksums are identical, you could pass 'false' to your modified AJAX call, which would tell it not to render anything over the table. If they aren't, you could pass it the HTML of the new table to render in place.

Answer (score 2):

it could be done but with mix of different technologies

if I would like to monitor in real time changes made in database I would think about triggers and sockets - trigger in database should call (on insert or update) function that will add event to queue - here's example function for postgresql (plsh is custom handler)

```
CREATE FUNCTION propagate_event(tablename) RETURNS text AS '
    #!/bin/sh
    # execute script that will add event to message queue
    /var/scripts/change_in_table.sh "$1"
' LANGUAGE plsh;
```

client connects to socket and receives that events in real time

Comment: You'd also have to use something like a Flash socket object as [Javascript doesn't support native sockets](http://haxe.org/doc/js/using_sockets_with_javascript) yet.

Comment: he can use socket.io :) and forget about it

Comment: Yes, socket.io uses a Flash socket object normally (though I think it can function without). Upvoted as this actually more accurately answers the question than mine.